# A snowglobe-esque world

Tags: planets, physics, gravity, worldbuilding-process

I'm imagining a world on the *inside* of a sphere, rather than on the outside. In this way it is effectively hollow, and gravity pulls equally "down" in all directions, with the center of the sphere having no gravity at all; so that one can walk anywhere in the surface of the sphere.

There is a "magical" light source at the center of the sphere, and the inverse-world supports a vast diversity of life. For right now, I'll say that the world is roughly the size of a small moon.

[image: From Interstellar, a similar concept]

I've been inspired by similar ideas from various sources, including the recent movie *Interstellar*. I understand that the strange gravity would cause strange weather, but realistically, how would this world act?

Comment: Please ask a more specific question. As this is put, it's probably too broad for this site.

Comment: What you have described is a variation on a Dyson Sphere (with your magical light source replacing the sun).  There are all sorts of discussions about practicality and behavior of such constructs that you can read.

Comment: See [this answer](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/61182/can-you-help-me-build-a-hollow-world/61190#61190).

Comment: I was trying to ask how the enviorment, i.e. weather, water, would act given that said uniformly-distributed inverted-gravity world already existed. It's sort of the opposite of the Dyson sphere. I may not be using the question system properly, I admit.

Comment: This reminded me of the interior of the ship in 2001: A Space Oddessy

Comment: *gravity pulls equally "down" in all directions* - this is true, in a way, but it really means that net gravity everywhere inside is 0. You need some other effect to keep things against the walls.

Comment: @Mołot OP could spin the sphere so that centrifugal force would apply to much of it

Comment: @Zxyrra Spinning an open sphere: the wind would get crazy.

Comment: @Zxyrra He could. I just wanted to point out false assumption in the question. By the way - where would they have horizontal land? in the "museum of the equator"? Spinning a sphere does not create a good surface to live on.

Comment: @Mołot I know, just brainstorming, the OP would have several problems to deal with